# grep/ag/etc results buffer: how to strip leading whitespace?

Tags: search, compilation-mode, grep

I'm using [ag.el](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el) as a front-end for the [ag](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) search utility. The results are displayed in a compilation buffer in the form `<file>:<line>:<column>:<matching-text>`. The matching-text includes leading-whitespace, and this makes the results harder to scan visually, in my opinion.

I dug around in the bowels of compile.el and ag.el hoping to find a way to strip the leading whitespace, but came up empty. Is there a way to accomplish this?

An example of search results in Emacs:
[image: emacs-results]

The same results in Vim (note the stripped whitespace):
[image]

Comment: One simple way to do this, would be to pipe the results through, say, `sed` before displaying them, though maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Also, in theory, you could have advised `compilation-filter` to call some function on the text it is going to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to @wvxvw for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to normalize the whitespace by advising `ag-filter`, which ag adds to `compilation-filter-hook`.

```
(defun ivan/filter-whitespace (prefix-pattern)
  (save-excursion
    (forward-line 0)
    (let ((end (point)) beg)
      (goto-char compilation-filter-start)
      (forward-line 0)
      (setq beg (point))
      (when (< (point) end)
        (setq end (copy-marker end))

        ;; normalize whitespace between prefix-pattern and rest of line
        (while (re-search-forward prefix-pattern end 1)
          (and (re-search-forward "[[:blank:]]*" end 1)
               (replace-match " " t t)))))))

(defun ivan/filter-ag-whitespace ()
  (ivan/filter-whitespace ag/file-column-pattern))

(advice-add 'ag-filter :after #'ivan/filter-ag-whitespace)
```

The structure of the filter is identical to `ag-filter` itself, just the `while` loop differs. I thought it might be nice to apply the same filter to the *Occur* buffer, but when all the results are from the same file I think the indentation lends worthwhile context.

The final result:
[image: normalized-whitespace]

*However*, the downside is this breaks wgrep functionality, probably because wgrep is looking for an exact match. I had to rig up a workaround that recompiles the search results with whitespace intact when wgrep is engaged.

```
(define-key ag-mode-map
  [remap wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode] #'ivan/init-wgrep-mode)

(defun ivan/init-wgrep-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (advice-remove 'ag-filter #'ivan/filter-ag-whitespace)
  (add-hook 'ag-search-finished-hook #'ivan/enable-wgrep-mode)
  (recompile))

(defun ivan/enable-wgrep-mode ()
  (remove-hook 'ag-search-finished-hook #'ivan/enable-wgrep-mode)
  (advice-add 'ag-filter :after #'ivan/filter-ag-whitespace)
  (wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode))
```